# Check Elements with the same Class and add new Element

Tags: jquery

I have multiple Divs with the same Class, when all Divs have the Class "hideaddress" then I insert an new Div. But when one of this Divs has not the Class "hideadress" I don't want to show the new Div. But it does not work. How can I change this??

```js
if ($('div').hasClass('hideaddress')) {
  $('<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address">new adress</div>').insertBefore('div.address:nth-child(1)');
}
```

```css
.hideaddress {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">4</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">5</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address showaddress">6</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jL9gedx/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$('.hideaddress').length === $('.address').length` to check if the common class name is exactly equal to the divs exists:

```js
if ($('.hideaddress').length === $('.address').length) {
  $('<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address">new adress</div>').insertBefore('div.address:nth-child(1)');
}
```

```css
.hideaddress {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">1</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">2</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">3</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">4</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address hideaddress">5</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 address showaddress">6</div>
```

---

This can also be checked:

```
if ($('.showaddress').length) { // it will check if this div exists.
```

Comment: @herrsaidy You can do this also: `$('.showaddress').length`.